# fetch inside fetch with incremental

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch

I have problem with loop and how rewrite whole array to get needed data.
i need to fetch data then nest "id" in next fetch to get data and merge 2 arrays.
How i can  get data outside of loop in another fetch then merge data ?

```js
    fetch(URL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        let companies = data;
        for (let i = 0; i <= companies.length; i++) {
          fetch(`URL${companies[i].id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              there loop is sending me data needed from 2nd fetch and 300 another data from first fetch.
            });
          // console.log(companies[i].name);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to merge the arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` for second fetch. Declare an array in the first fetch, whenever the data is retrieved in second fetch, push in array. Then you can access outside of for loop.

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users?since=135')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(async (data) => {
    let users = data;
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= users.length; i++) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${companies[i].login}`);
      const user = response.json();
      arr.push(user);
    }
    console.log(arr);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `await`ing in the loop is not very performant - it will end up requesting those urls sequentially, when actually you already have everything to do it in parallel. As suggested above, `Promise.all` would be needed in this case.
On the other hand, also remember that doing a lot of requests in parallel is also bad for performance, so in general it's best to process in chunks (there are libraries out there to do just that).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all()` to await for all `fetch` requests to complete. `Promise.all` takes an array of promises and returns a single promise which resolves when all of the passed promises resolve. If one of the passed promises rejects, `Promise.all` also rejects.

```
fetch(URL)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    let companies = data;
    let promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= companies.length; i++) {
      let promise = fetch(`URL${companies[i].id}`)
        .then(res => res.json());

      promises.push(promise);
    }

    Promise
      .all(promises)
      .then(dataArrays => {
          // dataArrays[0] is the result from company 0
          // dataArrays[1] is the result from company 1 and so on
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      // console.log(companies[i].name);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

However, if possible, combining all the `companies` requests into one and merging their data at the back-end will be the optimal solution as it will be more efficient.